# Find the angle at vertex $B$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the angle at vertex $B$ of a triangle in three-dimensional space whose vertices are
$A = (2;-1; 1)$, $B = (3; 2;-1)$ and $C = (7; 0;-2)$.

Need help so lost.

Answer (score 2):

Vectors AB and AC are $<1, 3, -2>$ and $<5, 1, -3>$ respectively.  The angle between these two vectors:
$$\theta = \cos^{-1} \Big( \frac{AB \cdot AC}{|AB||AC} \Big) = \cos^{-1} (14/490) = 88.36^o$$

Answer (score 1):

Find the vectors $\vec{BA}$ and $\vec{BC}$ and use the fact that for two vectors $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$

$$\vec{A}\cdot \vec{B} = |\vec{A}||\vec{B}|\cos\theta$$

Where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors.